# Expression for OrderBy linq with inner expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following expresssion for sorting:

```
this.Students = this.Students.OrderBy(x => x.ExamData.OrderByDescending(p => p.ExamDate).ThenByDescending(p => p.ExamId).FirstOrDefault().TotalMarks);
```

While my idea is to abstract the Expression for

```
x => x.ExamData.OrderByDescending(p => p.ExamDate).ThenByDescending(
                                  p => p.ExamId).FirstOrDefault().TotalMarks
```

to be made as an lambda Expression so that I can use like

```
this.Students = this.Students.OrderBy(sortExpression);
```

It's because I have many sort fields like the TotalMarks defined above, and I want to just create the Expression from the sort field and then call the OrderBy.

I know from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474643/building-an-orderby-lambda-expression-based-on-child-entitys-property), we can create an expression where child property is used, but not getting with the inner expressions.

Currently I have given a switch case and written the same stuff in each case like

```
this.Students = this.Students.OrderBy(x => x.ExamData.OrderByDescending(p => p.ExamDate).ThenByDescending(p => p.ExamId).FirstOrDefault().SubjectName);
```

So my idea is to create kindof ExpressionBuilder with a static method which builds the expression passing on the fieldName, like

```
public static Expression BuildSortExpression(string fieldName) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily pull most of the logic into a method:

```
private int sortExpression(Student x) { 
    return x.ExamData.OrderByDescending(p => p.ExamDate).ThenByDescending(p => p.ExamId).FirstOrDefault().TotalMarks;
}
```

Assuming `TotalMarks` is an `int`.

Then you would just need to use:

```
this.Students.OrderBy(x => sortExpression(x));
```

or add it as a property of Student.

Warning:
If you are using this with an ORM (linq to SQL, Entity framework, etc), this will not execute as efficiently as the previous code!

Comment: That wouldn't be converted properly by EF though.

Comment: Good point, although EF wasn't mentioned in the question, so I assumed it was a straight enumerable, but I will update the question.

Comment: He's referring to `Expression`, which tells us that this is an IQueryable.  It could be some other provider, such as Linq to SQL, which would support this, but EF is at least a likely option.

Comment: I totally agree, I just didn't think of it! Yours is probably the best answer (I have upvoted it), I will leave mine as it does provide the flexibility to order by desc too if needs be.

Comment: If you need a descending ordering you could just call `Reverse`, if the query provider supports that operation.  If not, you could provide an optional boolean to the helper method of `IsDecending`.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to create a reusable expression variable will end up being a lot more work than just creating your own extension method to do the whole ordering:

```
public static IQueryable<Student> OrderByMarks(this IQueryable<Student> students)
{
    return students.OrderBy(student => student.ExamData
        .OrderByDescending(exam => exam.ExamDate)
        .ThenBy(exam => exam.ExamId)
        .FirstOrDefault().TotalMarks);
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
this.Students = this.Students.OrderByMarks();
```

Comment: But its like the same which am doing right now as I will have to create the method for each property (field name), which is least likely an option for me, when going for refactoring.

Answer (score -1):

Got a solution for this using the  idea by Ben.
Created a

```
Dictionary<string, Func<Student, Object>>
```

with the sort fields as key and the func as

```
new Func<Student, object>((Student student) => { return GetLatestExam(student).TotalMarks; })
```

And the GetLatestExam static method as

```
private static Study GetLatestExam(Student student)
{
     return student.ExamData.OrderByDescending(p => p.ExamDate).ThenByDescending(p => p.ExamId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Then in the actual sort, I just have to call like this:

```
public void Sort(string sortField, bool sortAscending)
{
     // based on the sort field, get the sorting expression and execute.
     if(sortAscending)
     {
          this.Students= this.Students.OrderBy(student=>this._customSortColumns[sortField](student));
     }
     else
     {
          this.Patients = this.Patients.OrderByDescending(student=>this._customSortColumns[sortField](student));
     }
}
```

Comment: This is a LINQ to objects solution, but the OP is using a query provider.