# Construct LambdaExpression for nested property from string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I am trying to create a lambda expression for a nested property at run-time from the name of the propert. Basically I am trying to create the lambda expression specified by:

```
var expression = CreateExpression<Foo, object>(foo => foo.myBar.name);

private static Expression CreateExpression<TEntity, TReturn>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TReturn>> expression)
{
    return (expression as Expression);
}
```

With the classes:

```
class Foo
{
    public Bar myBar { get; set; }
}
class Bar
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

However all I am given is the type of `Foo` and the string `"myBar.name"`

If it were a normal property such as just needing the value `"myBar"` then I could use the following:

```
private static LambdaExpression GetPropertyAccessLambda(Type type, string propertyName)
{
    ParameterExpression odataItParameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "$it");
    MemberExpression propertyAccess = Expression.Property(odataItParameter, propertyName);
    return Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, odataItParameter);
}
```

However this code does not work for nested properties and I'm not sure how to create the LambdaExpression to do the work of `foo.myBar.name`.

I think it's going to be something like this:

```
GetExpression(Expression.Call(GetExpression(Foo, "myBar"), "name"))
```

But I can't seem to work out how to get it all working, or if there's a better way to do this at run-time.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
static LambdaExpression CreateExpression(Type type, string propertyName) {
    var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
    Expression body = param;
    foreach (var member in propertyName.Split('.')) {
        body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, member);
    }
    return Expression.Lambda(body, param);
}
```

For example:

```
class Foo {
    public Bar myBar { get; set; }
}
class Bar {
    public string name { get; set; }
}
static void Main() {
    var expression = CreateExpression(typeof(Foo), "myBar.name");
    // x => x.myBar.name
}
```

?

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I was looking for, my mistake was thinking that I needed to invoke the body expression (using `Call`) before getting the nested property.

Comment: Fantastic answer from Marc Gravell which solved it for me. As a bonus, resharper did this to your code:  

var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
Expression body = propertyName.Split('.').Aggregate<string, Expression>(param, Expression.PropertyOrField);
return Expression.Lambda(body, param);

Comment: It is realy cool. Marc, are there any way to use the same behaviour with nested list? I mean class Foo {public List<Bar> myBar { get; set; }}

Comment: @marc-gravell Any change to support indexers too (for arrays & lists)? like 
myBar.name[1].address[2]

Comment: @HamedFathi yes, but trickier; you need to use `Expression.Call` with the method-info of the relevant indexer accessor; see `Expression.Call` here: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4B0AMgJYB2AjpQKIIAOsAzl7RPVwDchNpxg8+9ADwYArDJzEANKQYAXFWAAWAQygA+faS6kAvKVIAKLitoBKM0a4BtWgF1hBIA== - note that you don't need the LdMemberToken - but you'd need to find the accessor via reflection

Answer (score 2):

For this method, `propertyPath` is `"Car", "Colour"` for `Driver.Car.Colour`.

```cs
public static MemberExpression NestedProperty(Expression propertyHolder, params string[] propertyPath)
{
    MemberExpression memberExpression = Expression.Property(propertyHolder, propertyPath[0]);

    foreach (var member in propertyPath.Skip(1))
    {
        memberExpression = Expression.Property(memberExpression, member);
    }

    return memberExpression;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To construct a lambda expression but with an inline solution you can do:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeOf(FooBar), "x");

// you "concat" your expression here :
var propertyExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "myBar");
propertyExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(propertyExpression, "name");
// expected result : "x.myBar.name" as a body expression

var expression = Expression.Lambda(propertyExpression, param);
// x => x.myBar.name
```