# C#: Search a list of defined queryable fields, different per model, with linq through generics (using entity framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

*****Scroll down for final working solution*****

All of my Entity Framework models use partials, which implement my own IEntity interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
        int Status { get; set; }
        int ID { get; set; }
}
```

This allows me to filter any Entity which implements this interface, based on the following function (simplified version):

```
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterByStatus<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int status) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        return query.Where(m => m.Status == status);
    }
```

Now I want a function which names all of the properties, which I might want to perform a text query on. Let's say that implementation Foo of IEntity has 2 values (Bar and Baz) that I want to perform queries on.

I currently have:

```
    public static IQueryable<Foo> FooSearch(this Entities context, string query)
    {
        IQueryable<Foo> result = context.Foo;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            result = result.Where(m =>
            m.Bar.ToLower().IndexOf(query.ToLower()) >= 0 ||
            m.Baz.ToLower().IndexOf(query.ToLower()) >= 0);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

But I want to set it up in a more generic way. Something like:

```
   public interface IEntity
    {
            int Status { get; set; }
            int ID { get; set; }

            string[] QueryableProperties { get; set; }
    }
```

And some kind of implementation like (pseudocode):

```
    public static IQueryable<T> GenericSearch(this IQueryable<T> query, string query) where T : class, IEntity
    {

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            query = query.Where(m =>
            m[QueryableProperties[0]].ToLower().IndexOf(query.ToLower()) >= 0 ||
                m[QueryableProperties[1]].ToLower().IndexOf(query.ToLower()) >= 0 ||
                // .... //
                m[QueryableProperties[QueryableProperties.Count - 1]].ToLower().IndexOf(query.ToLower()) >= 0)
        }
        return query;
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

******Working Solution******

Search function:

```
public static class SearchFilter
{
    private static Expression GetNestedPropertyExpression(Expression expression, string propertyName)
    {
        Expression body = expression;
        foreach (var member in propertyName.Split('.'))
        {
            body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, member);
        }
        return body;
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetSearchExpression<T>(string[] propertyNames, string query)
    {
        var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "category");
        MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
        MethodInfo toLowerMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);
        List<Expression> methodCalls = new List<Expression>();
        foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames)
        {
            var propertyExp = GetNestedPropertyExpression(parameterExp, propertyName);
            var queryValue = Expression.Constant(query.ToLower(), typeof(string));
            var toLowerMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, toLowerMethod);
            var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(toLowerMethodExp, containsMethod, queryValue);
            methodCalls.Add(containsMethodExp);
        }
        var orExp = methodCalls.Aggregate((left, right) => Expression.Or(left, right));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(orExp, parameterExp);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> Search<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string property) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        var filterAttributes = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(FilterableAttribute), true
        ).FirstOrDefault() as FilterableAttribute;

        if (filterAttributes == null) {
            return query;
        }

        var filterableColumns = filterAttributes.FilterableAttributes;
        if (filterableColumns == null || filterableColumns.Count() == 0)
        {
            return query;
        }

        if (property == null)
        {
            return query;
        }

        return query.Where(GetSearchExpression<T>(filterableColumns, property));
    }
}
```

Decorator (example: both a property of my model, and a nested property):

```
   [Filterable(FilterableAttributes = new string[] {
        nameof(Foo),
        nameof(Bar) + "." + nameof(Models.MyConnectedModel.Baz)
    })]
    public partial class MyConnectedModel: IEntity
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice question :)
Here's how you can do this:

```
static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(string[] propertyNames, string query)
{
  var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "category");
  MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
  MethodInfo toLowerMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower",Type.EmptyTypes);
  List<Expression> methodCalls = new List<Expression>();
  foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames)
  {
    var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);
    var queryValue = Expression.Constant(query.ToLower(), typeof(string));
    var toLowerMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, toLowerMethod);
    var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(toLowerMethodExp, containsMethod, queryValue);
    methodCalls.Add(containsMethodExp);
  }
  var orExp = methodCalls.Aggregate((left, right) => Expression.Or(left, right));

  return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(orExp, parameterExp);
}
```

And then you can use it like this (`query` is an `IQueryable<MyEntity>`)

```
query=query.Where(GetExpression<MyEntity>(queryableProperties,"SomeValue"));
```

Comment: This is a really nice answer, exactly what I was looking for. I implemented it in combination with this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208214/construct-lambdaexpression-for-nested-property-from-string) to include nested properties. I only have one issue still: because T is a generic type, and not an instance, I am unable to get `QueryableProperties`out of my type T, which means I still have to write a separate implementation for every search filter. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to do it the fancy way, you could create an attribute to denote that is is 'queryable' and decorate your properties with it. Then you can use reflection on the type itself to get all such properties. As an added benefit, you can ditch the list of strings for the property names.

Comment: Any chance you could edit your answer with a simple example? It would really help with learning more and better C# :) I am already looking into it, but I wonder if it will get me into trouble with the nested properties that I can now read out

Comment: Sure, I can take a look. Just post whatever you have now, so I don't have to recreate what you have from scratch.

Comment: I managed to get it working :) I updated the answer. Thank you for the function decorator idea - again you were spot-on!

Comment: I was actually thinking about something different, but this is a good approach as well. Thanks for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it can be surprisingly easy:

```
IQueryable<T> GenericSearch<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, string query)
{
    var queryableProperties = items
        .First()
        .GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        .ToList();

    return items.Where(i => queryableProperties.Any(p => ((string)p.GetValue(i)).Contains(query)));
}
```

This searches all properties of type `string` in a list of items.

It can be a class method, an extension method, a static function, it's easy to understand and works well. It can be extended to Fields or restricted to some interfaces easily.

Adjust to your liking.

Comment: This will only work for in-memory queries (i.e. LinqToObjects). `GetValue()` is a reflection method and therefore it cannot be translated into SQL when you want to use it with LinqToEntities.